# How to Change Swiping direction of CupertinoPageRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, gesturedetector

I’m using [Cupertino Page Route](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html) to produce the following Behavior

[image: GIF of Swipe CupertinoRoute Behavior]

```
      title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            //doesn't do what I want to do
            GestureDetector(             
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(settingsPage),
              onPanUpdate: (details){
                if(details.delta.dx < 0){
                  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(settingsPage);
                }
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.settings),
            ),
            //Not my concern for now
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            //Does what I want it to do
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(messages),
              child: Icon(Icons.message),
            ),                    
          ],
        ),
```

It allows me to swipe from **Left to Right** to close the *Message Screen*

Unfortunately it does not allow me to close the *Settings Screen* by **swiping** from **Right to Left**

Anyone one knows how to change the direction of the swipe for [CupertinoPageRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPageRoute-class.html) or mimic it's behavior with an other Solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you can easily change the swiping direction of CupertinoRoute but I’ve found two easy solutions for you :

- You could either use a [PageView Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) - which allows you to swipe between screens

*Or - better solution for your specific situation :*

- You could instead use the [page_transition Package](https://pub.dev/packages/page_transition) with a **Swipe Direction Detector**

This Second Solution will best reproduce the behavior of  `CupertinoPageRoute`

- *in addition it will provide you with animations going from HomeScreen to Settings/Messages but also back to your HomeScreen :*

[image: GIF of Solution]

This is how you could implement this second solution *shown in the GIF above into* your App :

```
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeScreen createState() => _HomeScreen();
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      //Use Page Transition left to right here
                      PageTransition(
                          // duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          type: PageTransitionType.leftToRightWithFade,
                          child: SettingsScreen(),
                          inheritTheme: true,
                          ctx: context),
                    ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black),
                )),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.black),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      //Use Page Transition right to left here
                      PageTransition(
                          // duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                          type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                          child: const MessageScreen(),
                          inheritTheme: true,
                          ctx: context),
                    ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: const Icon(Icons.message, color: Colors.black),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      //body
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your **Settings/Messages Screens** just implement a `GestureDetector` which will trigger on **Swipe**

It will Navigator.pop (close) your screen - & Flutter will take care of the reverse animation

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SettingsScreen createState() => _SettingsScreen();
}

class _SettingsScreen extends State<SettingsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
// This is where you detect swiping from right to left
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx < -10) {
// Upon swiping detection it then pops the screen - reverse animation happens without additional code
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },
        child: const Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          body: Center(child: const Text(" Settings")),
        ));
  }
}


// Same code here for your MessageScreen but with opposite swipe gesture detection (left to right)

class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessageScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MessageScreen createState() => _MessageScreen();
}

class _MessageScreen extends State<MessageScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: (details) {
          if (details.delta.dx > 10) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
        },
        child: const Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          body: Center(child: const Text(" Messages")),
        ));
  }
}
```

That's it ! - *the only down side to this method is once the swipe has been detected there is no way to cancel it*

---

---- *upon long discussion with the user - comments bellow have been addressed **above** & question edited*

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! 
However if I remove onTap nothing happens, and if I keep it and use the code you gave me it swipes from right to left and not left to right

Comment: Thank you but it still opens from right to left 
Maybe there's something else than GestureDetector that can do the job ?

Comment: You're asking a complete different question.. i've updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see your update last time, so now I tried your code and it works ! Thank you so much for your help !
It just doesn't swipe but there's no problem at least it opens from left to right, thank you !

Comment: I’m having a hard time seeing what you want to swipe right maybe you cloud send me a link to your UI - anyways glad i could help !

Comment: Mmh I searched an example but I don't find any
It's like a drawer but which will take full page 
So a drawer you can use your fingers to swipe right to left or left to right to open the drawer
I want to do the same thing but while opening full page
So if you take my last gestureDetector it opens right to left and if you swipe left to right then you will go back to the page you were
and I want to do the same for the left side
It's like a pageView but you open a whole new page instead of having always the same icons wherever you go

Comment: So Basically you have a sort of App Bar with 3 buttons ? One center - one left - one right ? - & you want to swipe the left button & get to the left page - swipe right button & get to the right page ? How big are your buttons ? *You wouldn't prefer to swipe the all screen ?*

Comment: Yes that's it ! They are average IconButton Well as long as it is possible to also change page by touching the buttons, and that I can start a whole new page, then yes I don't mind swiping the all screen

Comment: But why do you want to "Swipe" such small button isn't touching better ? if you want to have both touch and swipe on such small surface they will interfere as tapping and dragging out is interpreted as wanting to cancel a tap gesture - you could have one or the other but not really have both at the same time on a single button

Comment: Or is what you mean you want to "drag" the middle button to the left or right ? & separately touch the left & right button ?

Comment: I did a video on how works the right button and wanted to send it to you via wetransfer but we can't send anly link here, do you have any idea how I can pass it to you ?

Comment: try converting it to GIF it will be the easiest way

Comment: Alright I edited my post to put the gif ! So you can see on the right what it does
And I would like the same thing on the left
Thanks to your code it opens from left to right but I can't swipe back

Comment: Alright - could you provide your code for both the Setting Page & Message Page too please - for some reason this discussion won’t move to chat but you can always send me your discord if you need